# Linebreaks in title cause wrong line spacing

Tags: line-breaking, titles

On the title page of my thesis, I have a rather long title (on three lines), but I would like to specify which words fall on which line, because the default doesn't look good. 
Say I just use `\textbf{\LARGE{I have this really long title And I want to break it At specific locations}}` produces a page like this:
[image: No manual breaks]
I highlighted the places where I want to break the line with capital letters.

But if I do this:
`\textbf{\LARGE{I have this really long title\\ And I want to break it\\ At specific locations}}`,
the lines break correctly, but there is this gap produced, which I don't understand and definitely don't want.
[image: Manual breaks produce ugly gap]

It must be something to do with some of my settings or loaded packages?
This is the preamble and settings of the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright, english]{book}

% INSTAL THE PACKAGES I WILL MOST LIKELY NEED
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{latexsym, syntonly, textcomp, amsmath, caption, float}
\usepackage{graphicx}%[pdftex]
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%[outdir=./Figures/]{epspdfconversion}
\usepackage{blindtext, setspace, rotating}
\usepackage{natbib, longtable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable} %for footnote in tables
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %break line within long url
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
%in tabular environment: cell of fixed width with wrapping and align left (L), centred (C), aligned right (R)
%manual breaklines with \newline
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{titlesec} %manage space between chapter title and first section
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 18pt\raggedright}%
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{<after-sep>}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[top=2.3cm, inner=3.2cm, bottom=2.4cm, outer=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,%%%to have refences and links in blue
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
%% APPENDICES
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}  % for bold teletype font
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  %frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}
% NUMBER FIGURES AND TABLES BASED ON CHAPTERS
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LOWER CASE CHAPTER AND SECTION HEADINGS
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
            \markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
            \markright{\thesection\ #1}}
    \fancyhf{}  % delete current header and footer
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bfseries\thepage}
    %\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    %\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \addtolength{\headheight}{3pt} % space for the rule
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % and the line
        }
%\syntaxonly

\makeindex
    %attempt to make chapter headings start higher up
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1cm}{}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.7cm}{1.5cm}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.7cm}{0.5cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%% STARTING WITH THE ACTUAL DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% FRONT PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
\frontmatter
\doublespacing
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        \textbf{\LARGE{I have this really long title\\ And I want to break it\\ At specific locations}}         
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        By \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        My Name \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
 \vspace*{1\baselineskip} 
\singlespacing
        A thesis\\ submitted to University\\
        in fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of
        \\Doctor of Philosophy.\\
        \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
        University\\year
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

So how can I get my linebreaks AND line spacing correctly?

Comment: I don't know what half of your packages do, and I doubt you do either.  I would suggest you throw out everything and add packages when and if you need them.  First, double spacing is for typewriters, not typesetters.  Don't use it.  Second,  the starred version of \vspace is only useful a the top or bottom of a page.  Also, if \vspace is entered in the middle of a line, it will not be implemented until the end of the line.

Comment: Well, I am using a template handed down from one generation of students to another. You are right, I don't know what `latexsym, syntonly, textcomp` packages do - they were already a part of this template. But too many things went wrong when I tried to remove the packages or formatting commands that I didn't know. And for a two-line title, this works fine.

Comment: But I see what you mean that `\vspace` only works at the end of the line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\baselineskip` is a function of the font size.

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}{\LARGE\baselineskip=2\baselineskip% if you really need double spacing
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        \textbf{I have this really long title\\ And I want to break it\\ At specific locations}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
        By \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
        My Name \vspace{\baselineskip}%
}\\
        A thesis\\ submitted to University\\
        in fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of
        \\Doctor of Philosophy.\\
        \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
        University\\year
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```